# How do I force cursor:none to work when Safari keeps defocusing tab?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, safari

I have a Javascript game and I'm wanting to hide the cursor. No matter how I do the CSS, the cursor keeps popping back up. I finally realized what seems to be happening is, when my game plays a sound (using WebAudio), the browser displays a little speaker icon in the URL bar, and at that moment, takes the input focus away from the client area of the tab, so the CSS suddenly doesn't apply. I do not get a visibilitychanged event; the game keeps playing normally. And if I move the mouse, the cursor hides again until the next time a sound is played.

CSS things I've tried, all have no different impact:

```
 body, html {
    cursor: none !important; 
 }
 * {
    cursor: none !important; 
 }
 canvas {
    cursor: none !important; 
 }
```

The cursor stays hidden in Chrome, seems to only be a problem in Safari. I'm on Mac Ventura 13.2.1, running Safari 16.3.

Comment: Have you tried substituting an image e.g. `cursor: url(‘path-to-empty-image.png’);` ?

Comment: That's on my todo list, but I suspect the issue is Safari deciding the client area no longer has input focus, in which case it won't solve the issue. I might file a bug with Apple...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a transparent pixel as the cursor url did the trick for me:

```
cursor: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNgYAAAAAMAASsJTYQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=), auto !important;
```